# Getting error - Maximum number of memory segments that Notes can support has been exceeded (lotus notes)

Tags: lotus-notes, c#-2.0

I'm getting the error:

> Maximum number of memory segments that Notes can support has been exceeded

when removing increption while getting views (`getview()`) method called.

Comment: paste your code, please

Comment: Could you show the code that throws that error?!

Comment: _EInboxView             = _EncryptionDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)");

Comment: _EInboxView             = _EncryptionDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)");

Comment: You probably need to show all of your code, not just the line that throws the error.

Comment: I just noticed that this is a C# question. We definitely need to see all your code and specifically we need to see you are declaring and instantiating your session with Notes. And please answer this question: are you running on 64 or 32 bit Windows?

Comment: 32 bit windows. it gets error after increption removed  while getting one by one mail from inbox  that time 
 
_EInboxView = _EncryptionDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)");  gives problem